# Formview Insert Mode

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, formview

i am using formview and sqldatasouce. every thing is fine but when i have no record in my table nothing(no formview) is shown on the page. I want that when my table has no record then formview should be shown but in Insert Mode.

can any body help me to resolve this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like...

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (FormView1.DataItemCount == 0)
        {
            FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FormView.ChangeMode()` method to switch your form over to Insert mode.

Some code might look like this.

```
myFormView.DataBind();

if (myFormView.CurrentMode != FormViewMode.Insert)
{
   if (myFormView.DataItem == null)
   {
       myFormView.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Insert);
   }  
}
```